# how to replace with (tab or coma) using regexp the following context?

Tags: regex, preg-match, notepad++

i have the following set of records.

```
1 Colombo Kandy
1-1 Colombo Kegalle
1-1/245 Kegalle Negombo
1-2 Colombo Mawenella
1-3 Colombo Warakapola
1-4 Colombo Galapitamada
1/245 Negombo Kandy
1/744 Colombo Padiyapelella
1/744-3 Colombo Rikillagaskada
```

i want to replace the first space with coma,it means it will become as following

```
1,Colombo Kandy
1-1,Colombo Kegalle
1-1/245,Kegalle Negombo
1-2,Colombo Mawenella
1-3,Colombo Warakapola
1-4,Colombo Galapitamada
1/245,Negombo Kandy
1/744,Colombo Padiyapelella
1/744-3,Colombo Rikillagaskada
```

can anyone give me the regexp for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `(?m)^[^ \r\n]*\K[ ]` to find the first space in each line.
You could also use `(?m)^\S*\K[ ]` which doesn't allow tabs before the space.
Just replace with a comma.

Formatted:

```
 (?m)             # Multi-line mode
 ^                # Beginning of line            
 [^ \r\n]*        # Optional non-space, nor line break
 \K               # Construct, ignore previously matched
 [ ]              # A single space
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `^(\S+)\s`
Replace with: `$1,`

Where `\S` stands for any character that is not a space.